# How to abort spring-android rest template request in android

Tags: android, spring, abort, resttemplate

Is there any method availble in Spring-android library to abort rest template request?

Any pointers would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

I did not know about an funktion like you ask for.
But maybe you know a time for timeout. So you could use the connection timeout:
[RestTemplate Constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#RestTemplate(org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory))

```
int timeOutMillis = 5000;//example 5 seconds
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
            ((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) requestFactory).setConnectTimeout(timeOutMillis);
        } else {
            requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            ((HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) requestFactory).setConnectTimeout(timeOutMillis);
        }
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Alternativ you could create an AsyncTask and kill it :)

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.delete("http://example.com");
                return null;
            }
        }.execute(); //Task run

        task.cancel(true); //Cancel task and so the request
```

Hope that would be enough, sorry, but nothing else found in Spring Docs...